# Google Translate API - isReliable not returning anything

Tags: javascript, google-translate, google-translation-api

Has someone ever used **isReliable** with the Google Translate API? It always returns "undefined" value.

```
google.language.translate('hello','','es',function(result){
    alert(result.isReliable); // prints undefined
    alert(result.translation); // prints "hola"
});
```

Resources:
[Google Translate API - Result objects](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/reference.html#ResultObjects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **isReliable** - A boolean representing whether or not the
>   **detection** interval believes the language code is reliable for the
>   given text.

It only works for language detection (not for translation).

You can see an example [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/detection.html).

Comment: do you have an example of isReliable?

Comment: Yes, just view the source at the link I gave in the answer. After the `result` object is filled with the right data `isReliable` will get it's value. You can see this by using FireBug and setting break point at `if (!result.error) {`.